# How to Add a click Event Listener to nested class element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a click event listener to all the "question classes" nested deep inside the container class. I can't seem to figure out the issue here.

```js
let colorChange = document.querySelectorAll(".container .dropdowns .dropdown-function .question")
  for(i = 0; i < colorChange.length; i++){
    colorChange.addEventListener("click", function(){
      colorChange[i].classList.add("change-color");
    });
}
```

```css
.change-color{
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <main class = "dropdowns">
    <h1 class = "title">FAQ</h1>
    <div class = "dropdown-function">
      <h2 class = "question"> Question 1 </h2>
      <p class = "dropdown-content"> Answer 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class = "dropdown-function">
       <h2 class = "question"> Question 2 </h2>
       <p class = "dropdown-content"> Answer 2 </p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First, I will suggest you to notice if there is any error in console.*

You are trying to attach the event (*click*) to the [*`NodeList`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an individual element. Also declare the variable using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to create a block scope for the variable:

```js
let colorChange = document.querySelectorAll(".container .dropdowns .dropdown-function .question")
  for(let i = 0; i < colorChange.length; i++){
    colorChange[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      colorChange[i].classList.add("change-color");
    });
}
```

```css
.change-color{
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <main class = "dropdowns">
    <h1 class = "title">FAQ</h1>
    <div class = "dropdown-function">
      <h2 class = "question"> Question 1 </h2>
      <p class = "dropdown-content"> Answer 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class = "dropdown-function">
       <h2 class = "question"> Question 2 </h2>
       <p class = "dropdown-content"> Answer 2 </p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```